# window.location.href with dynamic parameter is not working with bottle webframework

Tags: javascript, jquery, bottle

In my JavaScript file, when button is pressed (client side):

```
window.location.href = "localhost:" + _portNo + "/startPlotting/" + _currentId;
```

Where `_portNo` and `_currentId` are global variables that are definitely set before calling this line (I have checked and double checked). In my server side (using bottle webframework) my route is like this:

```
@route('/startPlottingGraph/<id>',method='GET')
def patientList(id):#patient_id,name,surname):
    global _patientSock,_clientShareWindowFlag
    user = request.get_cookie("account",secret= _secretKey)
    print "id = ",id
    id = {'id':id}
    if((user[0] and user[1])):
            return template('plottingGraphPage')
```

When this route gets id parameter this gives me this error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: realTimeLineGraph is not defined //***(1)
```

Without `_currentId` parameter in:

`window.location.href = "localhost:" + _portNo + "/startPlottingGraph/"`

and without id parameter in `'/startplottingGraph'` get route it works like a charm. So what kind of approach should I follow?

*(1) this line I intentionally left without explanation I guess it is not the source of the problem*

Comment: Isn't it `window.location.href`? Your first code snippet refers to `window.href.location`...

Comment: yeah it is window.location.href, sorry

Comment: I just noticed that the first line of code also has: `"/startPlotting/" + _currentId;`.  Is that meant to be `"/startPlottingGraph/"` instead?  (Maybe this is the issue...)

Comment: ayy, sorry again I was in hurry when posted it. let me now do corrections